# Get json data from file at random locations

Tags: php, json, server-side

I am trying to upload files with json data to a php server at my web-hotel, but on the serverside the php is not able to locate the file I`m sending up.
I have tried like this

```
   require_once 'db.php';
    $jsondata = file_get_contents("movies.json");
    $json = json_decode($jsondata,true);

    echo $json['movies'][0]['title']; 
    $output ="<ul>";
    foreach($json['movies'] as $movie){
        $output .="<h4>".$movie['title']."</h4>";
        $output .="<li> Year".$movie['year']."</li>";
        $output .="<li> Genre".$movie['genre']."</li>";
        $output .="<li> Director" .$movie['director']."</li>";

    }
    $output .="</ul>";
    echo $output;


?>
```

Which works perfectly fine if I have a file called "movies.json" in the same directory as the PHP code, but my problem is, that I send the file from different raspberry pi´s, so I do not have an URL for the file_get_contents(), so how do I overcome this?

Any response would be appreciated

Comment: Your raspberry Pi can't give the URL to your PHP code in some way? It's very common API behavior to have external services give extra informational calls like this to provide it with enough data to execute tasks.

Comment: Hi Jay Blanchard
Thanks for taking the time answering my question.
i got it solved now. 
To upload json data the syntax is apparently
 "$json = file_get_contents('php://input');" - then the data can be processed  :)